# NUnit/Microsoft.DependencyInjection - Use one ServiceProvider object for all [TestFixture] classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nunit

In a C# project with Microsoft.DependencyInjection, we have this `DepInj` class with one `static` method that does the interface-class association:

```cs
public static void AssociateInterfacesClasses(IServiceCollection p_secServices)
{
    p_secServices.AddScoped<IScopedClass, ScopedClass>();

    p_secServices.AddTransient<ITransientClass, TransientClass>();
}
```

In the project, the classes' constructors receive an `IServiceProvider` parameter that is assigned to a private field, which is in turn used to access the objects the methods need.

In our test project, I'll need those same objects. I want to test method `UsefulMethod(ITransientClass p_objTransient)` from `ScopedClass`. So I need to create an `ITransientClass` object before calling `UsefulMethod()`.

It's simple enough to have a `OneTimeSetUp` method in `TestScopedClass`, that will look like this:

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void InitTestScopedClass()
{
    IServiceCollection z_secServices = new ServiceCollection();
    DepInj.AssociateInterfacesClasses(z_secServices);
    _sepProvider = z_secServices.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

with `_sepProvider` a private field in `TestScopedClass`. I can then use it to create `ITransientClass` objects to test `UsefulMethod()` with.

It's simple enough, but I have several classes to test, and I'm wondering how I could create a `ServiceProvider` object once and make it accessible from the various `TextFixture` classes.

The most immediate solution would be a `SetUpFixture` class like this:

```cs
[SetUpFixture]
public class MainSetUp
{
    public static ServiceProvider MyProvider;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetStuffUp()
    {
        IServiceCollection z_secServices = new ServiceCollection();
        DepInj.AssociateInterfacesClasses(z_secServices);
        MyProvider = z_secServices.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TidyStuffUp()
    {
        MyProvider.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, it uses a `static` field, which I've been warned against as code smell in a lot of situations.

Is it good practice? Is there a better practice?

(Additionally, should this question be moved to Design?)